# Is it a correct way to read a file contents using paramiko (SSH, SFTP client)?

Tags: python, ssh

Is my implementation of `_read_contents` (3 lines) fine, or does it create a potential problem (e.g. passing part of an object that has to be destroyed, or a connection that cannot be closed, etc.)? **I don't need the review of the general design, only these 3 lines.**

```
import paramiko  
#################################################################################
class StorageSFTP:

  def __init__(self, ssh_client_params):
    self.ssh_client_params = ssh_client_params

    ###############################################################################
  def __enter__(self):
    self.ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    # AutoAddPolicy explained in --> https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/use-paramiko-python-to-ssh-into-a-server/
    self.ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.ssh_client.connect(**self.ssh_client_params)
    self.sftp_client = self.ssh_client.open_sftp()
    return self

  def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.sftp_client.close()
    self.ssh_client.close()
  ###############################################################################
  def _read_contents(self, my_filename):
    with self.sftp_client.open(my_filename) as sftp_file:
      contents = sftp_file.read()
      return contents
```

Usage (dummy example):

```
  with StorageSFTP({...}) as my_stft:
    c = my_stft._read_contents("my_filename")
  print(c[:100])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pair of high-level isssues with this design.

1. declaring object attributes
2. object (session) lifetimes

You offered example usage; thank you.
I'm going to pretend it was this slightly more complex example:

```
def retrieve_files(ssh_client_params,
                   filename1="my_filename",
                   filename2="another_filename"):
    with StorageSFTP(ssh_client_params) as my_stftp:
        c = my_stftp._read_contents(filename1)
        d = my_stftp._read_contents(filename2)
    return c, d
```

That is, I'm going to assume a design where
we authenticate once then retrieve several files.
Creating a connection and authenticating
costs roughly half a second across a WAN.
We wish to amortize that cost over the retrieval
of several short files.

If that's not a requirement for *your* use case,
then there's other ways to design the Public API
if you get to re-authenticate once per file.

---

## declare attributes in constructor

```
  def __init__(self, ...):
    self.ssh_client_params = ...

  ##### Uggh! Please elide this ASCII art. #######
  def _open(self):
    self.ssh_client = ...
    self.sftp_client = ...
```

There are three object attributes that a
maintenance engineer has to keep in mind.
One of them is declared up-front in the `__init__` ctor
where it should be, thank you.
The other two are created later in the object's lifetime.
Please don't do that.
You don't *have* to,
but it is polite to tell the Gentle Reader about them
by initializing each one to `None`
if you're not quite ready for them yet.
Some linters will flag this issue.

I recommend that you store an open `self.sftp_client` attribute
in `__init__`, and let the other (local!) variables go out of scope,
as you won't need them again.

---

## object lifetimes

You have exactly the right idea that using a
[with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)
context manager helps app developers prevent resource leaks.
But the OP code does not appear to work correctly,
since it doesn't implement methods required by the protocol.
I tried this under cPython 3.11:

```
>>> class StorageSFTP:
...     def _open(self):
...         print('open')
...     def _close(self):
...         print('close')
...     def get(self):
...         print('get')
... 
>>> with StorageSFTP() as s:
...     s.get()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'StorageSFTP' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

Unsurprisingly it fails.
A context manager must implement `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

Usually it is more convenient to use a
[@contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)
decorator.

The leading `_` underscore to denote a `_private()` method
*can* be helpful. But here we have ignored the mandatory
method names, whose spelling cannot change from the protocol spec,
and we have a private `_read_contents()` method
which should actually be part of the Public API.
Just rename it to `read_contents()`.

You may find `from contextlib import closing` convenient.
If you're looking for an easy-to-apply pattern,
just stick to using the `@closing` decorator.
App developers will always use `with` to obtain an instance,
and your `def close` will always execute at the end,
even if a fatal exception happened somewhere in the app code.
When you write that `close` method,
feel free to log `"Closing..."`,
so you can convince yourself that it's happening
when you anticipated.

---

This code does not achieve its design goals.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

---

EDIT:

It appears the OP has altered the code.

The `def _open` method I reviewed has been renamed to `__enter__`.
Similarly `def _close` became `__exit__`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed review. I have extracted bits from a much bigger class, so _read_contents() is actually private, I am using system variables for authentication, etc.

Comment: Your snippet with `c` and `d` is correct, i.e. no leaks, resources left unopened etc., right? That's all I was asking about :)

Comment: The project is about backing up Medium and Wordpress websites, and copy-pasting the files between the cloud servers (GitHub, SFTP, PCloud and local storage) in general. The repository is here - https://github.com/yu51a5/wordpress_backup - it does what's needed, but not very polished. If something in this repository looks interesting enough to review, I will gladly ask the questions so that you can add your comments as reviews on this website.

Comment: In StoragePCloud, these identifiers seem a bit suspect: `__post __post_fileid __post_folderid __get_id __get_content_inner`. That is, it's my opinion that name mangling is seldom what's wanted and that it isn't something _you_ want in _this_ particular code. Recommend you use single leading `_` underscore to denote `_private()`, not two, which has [another meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private/70900#70900). Also use [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) on your source code, or at least use four spaces. Don't nest functions.

Comment: These are private methods that are local to this class. Naming is not my strongest skill, admittedly - can change them if you think the private names are a priority. But I am more worried about the overall design at the moment.

Comment: There are tries-catches missing, I have not declared the types of the method arguments and outputs etc. - this might need to be changed. But maybe there are even more important ToDos?

Comment: I'm saying that `abc`, `_def`, and `__ghi` are three _very_ different kinds of names, and that you should probably avoid the last kind. The `__` double underscore is asking python to do things that you don't want it to do. If you want to make everything public (no single leading underscore), that's fine. // Using `mypy` with optional type annotations is up to you, take advantage of such linting or not, as you wish. Me? I find it helpful, so I tend to annotate most of my methods.